# Visual C++ redistributable doesn't install libraries needed

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

So I have made an application with Visual C++ and SFML. I used Visual Studio 2015 as the IDE.

Now when I try to run the applications on computers without VS2015 Visual C++ installed, I get the errors that some libraries are missing.

Then I try to install the Visual C++ redistributable 2015 packet which should remove these missing libraries errors.

After that when I try to run the Application again the same errors append.

These are the libraries missing:

- vcruntime140d.dll
- ucrtbased.dll
- mavcp140d.dll

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Is your application x86 or x64? Are you running ``VCREDIST_X86.EXE`` or ``VCREDIST_X64.EXE``? What operating system and service pack level is the target machine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are the *Debug* versions of the C/C++ Runtime. They are not deployed by the VCREDIST as you are expected to ship the *Release* build of your application.

For testing, you can use side-by-side deployment of the *Debug* CRT or use the provided Debug MSM modules if you have an MSI based setup. You can't ship your application using *Debug*.

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293574.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for pointing out to ship the Release Build, this was my mistake.